# how to delete node and all related nodes not only the relations -- neo4j cypher 1.8

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, neo4j

how to delete node and all related nodes not only the relations
For Example

```
account-[:GGroup]-group,
group-[:GEvent]-event,
group-[:GMember]-member,
group-[:GAlbum]-album,
album-[:GPhoto]-photo,
```

So I want to delete group with all related nodes (event and album( and photo)), this is my work ... I'm using java.

```
    START group = node:GGroup('dbId:1') 
    MATCH group-[gp:privacy]-gPrivacy,
            group-[gm:GroupMember]-(),
            group-[ge:GroupEvent]-event,
            event-[ep:privacy]-gePrivacy,
            event-[eep:EventParticipant]-(),
            event-[ea:EventAlbum]-eventAlbum,
            eventAlbum-[ap:privacy]-geaPrivacy,
            eventAlbum-[aph:AlbumPhoto]-eventAlbumPhoto,
            eventAlbumPhoto-[ept:PhotoTag]-eventAlbumPhotoTag,
            event-[ev:EventVideo]-eventVideo,
            eventVideo-[vp:privacy]-gevPrivacy,
            group-[ga:GroupAlbum]-groupAlbum,
            groupAlbum-[gap:privacy]-gaPrivacy,
            groupAlbum-[aphoto:AlbumPhoto]-groupAlbumPhoto,
            groupAlbumPhoto-[gpt:PhotoTag]-groupAlbumPhotoTag,
            group-[gf:GroupFile]-groupFile 
            delete group,gm,ge,event,ep,gePrivacy,eep,ea,eventAlbum,ap,geaPrivacy
            ,aph,eventAlbumPhoto,ept,eventAlbumPhotoTag,ev,eventVideo,vp,gevPrivacy,ga,
            groupAlbum,gap,gaPrivacy,aphoto,groupAlbumPhoto,gpt,groupAlbumPhotoTag,gf,
            groupFile,gp
```

Answer (score 1):

```
START g=node({id_of_group_node})
MATCH acc-[ag:GGroup]-g
     ,g-[ge:GEvent]-e
     ,g-[gm:GMember]-m
     ,g-[ga:GAlbum]-a
     ,a-[ap:GPhoto]-p
DELETE g, ge, e, gm, m, ga, a, ap, p, ag
```

Comment: sorry for late reply , but this query doesn'y work it delete the group only

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal working example of your database on http://console.neo4j.org/ and update your question with a link to it?

Comment: here is my work and I want to delete all nodes except what I replaced with ()

Answer (score 0):

in case you want to delete all related nodes, there is no need to explicitly match them one by one in the MATCH phase. you can simply find all except the starting one (+ the album photos):

```
START account=node(...)
MATCH account-[:GGroup]-group,
      group-[r1]-all,
      group-[:GAlbum]-()-[r2]-photo
WHERE Id(all)<>Id(account)
DELETE group, r1, all, r2, photo.
```

Comment: sorry for late reply , but this query doesn'y work it delete the group only